# how can my WPF launch two windows?

Tags: c#, wpf

apologies, really new C# learner. my application will have these windows:

- a main display window
- an option panel to change what's on the display window

how can I make it so that when the application starts, both of these windows open, and how would I go about making user decisions in the options window affect display in the main window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `OnStartup` method of `App.xaml.cs`, add the following:

```
Window2 window = new Window2();
window.Show();
```

and the main window will be displayed by default since it is defined as the start window in your `App.xaml` property `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`

Comment: `public partial class App : Application 
    {
        Window1 optionsWindow = new Window1();
        optionsWindow.show();
    }`

Thanks. So I make an instance of Window1 and then show it. VS tells me 'App.optionsWindow' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'. Know what to do about this?

Comment: @michael.greenwald no that's wrong you declare the optionsWinow like what you mentioned but `optionsWindow.show();` must be inside a method not in the class directly. so but it inside `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) { optionsWindow.show(); }`

Comment: you don't have to call it, it well be called automatically whatever you but in this method is called on the start up of the application

Answer (score 3):

In the main window's constructor, create a new instance of the Options window class and call `Show()`.

To make the two classes interact, you can pass a reference to the main window to the options window.